# Text fields don't get updated using the browser back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, web-applications, web

I have been looking for information about this but I don't get with the solution.

I have some text fields on a page which I get updated on `blur` making use of jQuery events.
There's no form to submit, the update took place in the background using jQuery `$.post`.

If a user updates those inputs, then clicks on a link to go to another section of the page and then comes back using the browser's **back button**, those inputs won't show the last values set by the user but the previous ones in case there were, or empty text inputs if there weren't.

Users are reporting this as a bug (even is more a browser behavior), and I wonder if there is any solution for this.

I have been taking a look at things like [this](http://www.contentedcoder.com/2012/03/jquery-ui-autocomplete-back-button.html) or [this](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1584-Preventing-Form-Caching-With-Javascript-And-jQuery.htm), but they don't solve the problem I have. I have no forms, I have no submit and I don't want to reset the form.

I've noticed this problem doesn't take place in IE 9 and either in Firefox but it does on Chrome.

The user can navigate to different pages (more than 30) with more than 12 text fields in each and therefor I have discarded the idea of storing them on sessions.

Is there any way to solve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if my solution can solve you're problem , but:

what if you bind `data` to you're input? e.g you can set dinamically data on `input`

```
$('input').data( 'val' , $(this).val());
```

and then re-bind it through

```
$('input').val( $(this).data() ) ;
```

Do not follow exactly these lines of code , I'm trying to give you an idea of what I'm wondering. I hope that it can help you. 
http://api.jquery.com/data/ doc for `.data()`